# inline edit dialog in salesforce

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to access the input elements in the dialog box from a jquery script places in the main page(background), but I am unable to do so. This dialog box pops up when I doubleclick on the Billing address field in the main page.

PLease let me know on how to access the form elements in the dialogbox from the main page?

Edited:

Actually when the contact page detail page is loaded, you wouldn't find a field with the id con19country, but only after you double click the mail address this field becomes available in the DOM. Also the div(id=InlineEditDialog) that holds the fields that becomes visible when double clicked on mailing address is also grayed out in the HTML. Check the image here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cdd4.jpg

Edited again:

I was able to access the dialog box finally..

```
    j$("[id*=_ilecell]").bind('dblclick', function(){
        var elementID = j$(this).attr('id');
        if (!sfdcPage.editMode)
        sfdcPage.activateInlineEditMode();

        if (!sfdcPage.inlineEditData.isCurrentField(sfdcPage.getFieldById(elementID)))
        sfdcPage.inlineEditData.openField(sfdcPage.getFieldById(elementID));
        stateCountryAutocomplete();
    });
});
```

You can also refer this blog for further help: http://blog.force365.com/2012/07/30/ui-tips-and-tricks-country-list/

Regards
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use Firebug (or any other developer tools) in the browser of your choice to learn these.

In this example BillingStreet can be obtained by `$('#acc17street').html()`

[image: firebug example]

But fear not, there are compiled lists of known standard field Ids. Scroll a bit for example here: http://phollaio.tumblr.com/post/22058016777/how-to-obtain-a-field-id and consider leaving a nice comment for this guy so it doesn't look like I stole his hard work in this question giving nothing in return ;)

---

EDIT :) What exacly are you after? Do you want to capture the content of this box? Or address details in general? Or do something after OK is clicked? I think you'd have to inspect functions visible when you hover over the address field.

```
<td 
onmouseover="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" 
onmouseout="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" 
onfocus="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOverField(event, this);" 
ondblclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.dblClickField(event, this);" 
onclick="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.clickField(event, this);" 
onblur="if (window.sfdcPage && window.sfdcPage.hasRun) sfdcPage.mouseOutField(event, this);" id="con19_ilecell"
class="dataCol col02 inlineEditWrite">
    <div id="con19_ileinner">2335 N. Michigan Avenue, Suite 1500<br>Chicago, IL 60601, USA<br> </div>
</td>
```

Try to find definition of this sfdcPage and if you can override some of the functions with "whatever they were doing originally + your behavior"? It's an object constructed from prototype called `DetailPage` and you can find the definition in `/jslibrary/(some timestamp)/sfdc/main.js`

Comment: I have implemented autocomplete functionality using the jQuery Autocomplete plugin. I have implemented autocomplete on country and state fields in the edit page. But I am unable to do so on the dialog box which comes up. This thing is killing me!!

Comment: I was able to solve this issue.. I used the below code:  j$("[id*=_ilecell]").bind('dblclick', function(){
   var elementID = j$(this).attr('id');
   if (!sfdcPage.editMode)
   sfdcPage.activateInlineEditMode();
   
   if (!sfdcPage.inlineEditData.isCurrentField(sfdcPage.getFieldById(elementID)))
   sfdcPage.inlineEditData.openField(sfdcPage.getFieldById(elementID));
   stateCountryAutocomplete();
  });
 });

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.. I also referred this blog: http://blog.force365.com/2012/07/30/ui-tips-and-tricks-country-list/

Comment: Coll, this might come handy in future :) Can you maybe edit your question a bit so people can find it when looking for binding autocomplete to edit page and inline edit :)